# Dateparse in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tableau-desktop

How do I convert this (see formula below) formula using SQL? I normally use it in Tableau-BUT this formula doesn't work when creating relationships in Tableau. I have three tables (Custom SQL) using three different DATES to create relationships. I wonder if I could use something similar in SQL.

DATEPARSE('yyyyMM',str(DATE))

My raw data shows 202201,202202,202203 --Using the formula above converts the dates to Jan 2022, Feb 2022 and Mar 2022 etc.

Thanks

Comment: But "202201" is not an actual date, is it? So you just want to translate the values of the last 2 characters (careful what you assume) to the English month abbreviation. There are a variety of ways to do that. Perhaps you should consider storing an actual date and not a partial one as a string. You will find that schema problems make using your data far more difficult.

Comment: YES, unfortunately in my raw data this is a date 202201 (Created and Completed Date). I have 3 SQL tables --one will be used as my main table --Say TABLE A, then I will create a relationship between Table A and Table B- Then another relationship between Table A and Table C.

Comment: A date has 3 parts - month, day and year. You may not always display all 3 parts, but for a true date, they need to be there to create a date. You can default to the first of the month, or whatever day you like if you are missing that info.

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server you can simply append a `01` and then convert to a date.  Then it becomes a small matter for `format()`.   A word of caution...  `format()` has some great features but it is not very performant.   ***Use it sparingly***

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeCol int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (202201)
,(202202)
,(202203)


Select SomeCol
      ,NewValue = format(try_convert(date,concat(SomeCol,'01')),'MMM yyyy')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol NewValue
202201  Jan 2022
202202  Feb 2022
202203  Mar 2022
```

Comment: I think `format` is not necessary. The tableau function converts the string to date, but the op's default settings for tableau is showing him in that format. I suggest just using the result of the try_convert.

Comment: @tinazmu Fair but OP wanted a "formula using SQL? "

Comment: If course. Your answer is correct either way. I just wanted to point out for the benefit of OP

Comment: @JohnCappelletti--Thanks I will try the suggestion--I'm New to SQL world --In fact, I just signed up for a SQL Course.

Comment: @Floki_Sand Congrats on taking that step.  It will be well worth your time.